# Does command "fatattr" preserve timestamp?

Tags: linux, usb

Nowadays USB sticks and other storage devices connecded by USB are widly used. And because of compatibility reasons it is best to leave the original formatting FAT32.

Yet often an USB stick contains
important data to be preserved additionally to temporary data which are permanently edited.

In such cases it is appropriate to set some aerea to readonly.

Shortly I found the command "fatattr" which makes that possible in Linux.

I have downloaded, installed and applied this new command.

Today I see that the timestamp of that directory was reset to 1979.

Is this a feature of fatattr or have I made something wrong.

Regards

Comment: Please be aware that many operating systems **completely ignore** the read-only attribute of folders, and treat "read-only" on *files* as just a hint, easily overcome. You might consider using Zip compression, perhaps with password, to better protect files on the USB. Another option is to make a separate FAT32 partition on the USB drive for certain files.